Bernstein's inequality for a disc (Wolf Notes)
I'm trying to understand the proof of Bernstein’s inequality for a disc on page 30 of Wolff's notes on Harmonic analysis. I asked an earlier question about the proof but I'm still struggling with the proof.
From the previous theorem, we know that $\phi \in \mathcal{S}$ (Schwartz space) such that $\hat{\phi}$ is equal to $1$  on $D(0, 1)$ (the disk of radius $1$ centered at $0$). We also have $\phi^{R^{-1}}(x) = R^n\phi(R^{-1}x)$ (where we are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$). If we let $\psi = \phi^{R - 1}$ then it satisfies.
$$\|\psi\|_r = CR^{n/r'}.$$
I can show this now. But then it says

using the chain rule
$$\|\triangledown \psi\|_1 = R\|\phi\|_1.$$

I can't figure out this is true. I've been able to relate $\|\triangledown \psi\|_1$ to $\|\triangledown \phi\|_1$ but not to $\|\psi\|_1$.Can someone help explain how to relate these two?
